# Android Studio with OpenGLES: How to navigate back to main menu after closing GLSurfaceview.Renderer?

Tags: android-studio, opengl-es

I hope you can help me, I am learning OpenGL ES. I have this part of code in Android Studio:

```
            RadioGroup rgOptions = findViewById(R.id.rgOptions);
            optionSel = rgOptions.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if (optionSel > 0){
                switch (optionSel){
                    case R.id.rbPoint:
                        renderer = new RendererPoint();
                        break;
                    case R.id.rbPoligon:
                        renderer = new RendererPoligon();
                        break;
                }
                view.setRenderer(renderer);
                setContentView(view);
                view.requestRender();
            }
```

Then, my GLSurfaceview.Renderer executes normally, and now when I press the return button of the emulator I want to go to the main menu; at this moment the application closes.